# In lumen,How to call another trait's function in trait

Tags: laravel, traits, lumen

I have two traits in my lumen application CommonTrait and PaymentTrait. 
Helpers/CommonTrait has following method:

1.sendMail
2.calculateAmount

Helpers/PaymentTrait as following method
1. Addorder
2. Addtrans.
3. GenerateContForMail

I want to use sendmail method into paymentTrait's GenerateContForMail method .
Lumen give me following error:

```
Fatal error: Trait method sendEmailNotification has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\PaymentController in D:\xampp7.1.9\htdocs\bloxin-app-api\app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\PaymentController.php on line 28
```

Please help to resolve with issue. I am new in lumen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Use something like this:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller {
use A, B {
    PaymentTrait::sendEmailNotification insteadof AnotherTrait;
   }
}
```